# Extracting specific values with Postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql, substring, extract

I have a table like this:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtavU.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>data</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>creator_a@creator.com</td>
    <td>"vimeo_profile"=>"", "twitter_profile"=>"", "youtube_profile"=>"", "creator_category"=>"production_company", "facebook_profile"=>"", "linkedin_profile"=>"", "personal_website"=>"", "instagram_profile"=>"", "content_expertise_categories"=>"4,5,8"</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>creator_b@creator.com</td>
    <td>"twitter_profile"=>"", "creator_category"=>"association", "facebook_profile"=>"", "linkedin_profile"=>"", "personal_website"=>"", "content_expertise_type"=>"image", "content_expertise_categories"=>"4, 6"</td>  
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And I want to query this using PostgreSQL, so I only get the values regarding `content_expertise_categories`:

*Important to mention that the number of values vary. The table has many more entries so I am looking for a solution that helps me extract the values regardless of whether there are 2 or 15 values to pull out.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG3Np.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>data</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>creator_a@creator.com</td>
    <td>4,5,8</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>creator_b@creator.com</td>
    <td>4,6</td>  
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried `substring` but can't make it to work.

Some help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and include the data and desired results in the question.  Questions on Stack Exchange should not simply be links to other web sites.

Comment: `select (string_to_array(data,'"content_expertise_categories"=>'))[2];`

Comment: thanks for the swift reply Vao; could you include in the select the fields I am trying to select "email" & "data" as well as the "from" (table name is "users")? thanks very much!

Comment: `select (string_to_array(data,'"content_expertise_categories"=>'))[2] as data, email from users;` ?..

Comment: Thanks Vao. I am using Navicat 9.1.2 and get an error that says:    "ERROR:  function string_to_array(hstore, unknown) does not exist
LINE 2: select (string_to_array(data,'"content_expertise_categories"...
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: `select (string_to_array(data::text,'"content_expertise_categories"=>'::text))[2] as data, email from users;` that's why images that you posted were not enough :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your incredibly quick answers Vao. I guess all the info needed is posted here now but more than happy to update the post in a better way if any suggestions come my way. Again, thanks very much! :)

Comment: so that was the needed query then, @Henry?

Comment: Just had to make a slight change to pull the info as I wanted. Resulting query is this: SELECT email,(string_to_array(data::text,'"content_expertise_categories"=>'::text))[2] FROM users

Comment: cool then - I post it as answer. You are very welcome :)

Comment: @vao have a couple of questions on the code though. Whats the purpose of using this "data::text" and this "[2]". Also, how would you modify the code if the parameter "content_expertise_categories"=> is in the middle of the string?, like this: "vimeo_profile"=>"", "twitter_profile"=>"", "youtube_profile"=>"", "content_expertise_categories"=>"4,5,8", "creator_category"=>"production_company", "facebook_profile"=>"", "linkedin_profile"=>"", "personal_website"=>"", "instagram_profile"=>""

Comment: @vao Thanks very much for your update. The more elegant solution works as a charm. Again, very much appreciated all your help! :-)

Comment: @Henry, my pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  email,
  (string_to_array(
    data::text,'"content_expertise_categories"=>'::text
    )
  )[2] as data 
FROM users
;
```

**Update:**

In your example all strings have "content_expertise_categories" listed last, which allows to think you can just split string to two pieces. If you happen to have more php array definition values after, you'll need an additional split on `',"'` and taking [1] part this time...

Mind casting column `"data"` to `::text` before using it in `content_expertise_categories` function, as it requires text type, and your column appeared to be not such.

I believe more elegant would be this query:

```
select 
  email,
  data->'content_expertise_categories' as data
from h
;
```

But when I was posting first query I did not know that you use hstore

Comment: *"Code-only"* answers are not recommended. They don't explain why your code is right and why the OP's code, if any, is wrong. Even if the code is intuitive to you, or to someone who is proficient at the programming languages and/or APIs being used, it's good practice that answers include explanation so that even someone new to programming can learn how to solve the problem not only with *what* code works, but also, and a lot more importantly, *why* that code works.